# extractTo - кириллические файлы

Tags: php, zip

Здравствуйте. Архив не хочет распаковывать кириллические файлы. В чем может быть проблема ?

```
for ($i=0; $i<$numFiles; $i++) {
       $data_files=$zip->statIndex($i);
       $name=iconv('CP866', 'UTF-8', $data_files['name']);
       $fileList[]=$name;
}                                           

$zip->extractTo($dir_zip, $fileList);
```

Comment: А что за понятие "кириллические файлы" такое?

Comment: название файла на русском языке

Comment: Да вот в этой перекодировке проблема и есть, я думаю. Пробуйте без перекодирования имени. Или второй параметры при извлечении не указывайте.

Comment: ничего не изменилось. У меня выборочные файлы загружаются, поэтому второй параметр нужен

Comment: если делать вывод `var_dump($fileList);` то все имена есть в массиве. А вот сам метод выгружает только файлы с именами  латинницей

Comment: Тут https://toster.ru/q/41954 комментарии к ответу почитайте.